# Console Screen printing bug at max line with escape code to set Cursor's position

Tags: python, shell, console, escaping, ansi-escape

simplified code, original `_` could be more than 2 length

```
import msvcrt
import os
os.system(f'mode con: cols={100} lines={10}')

_=''
while True:
    print('\r'+' '*9+f'{_}')
    print('TypeHere:\0337',end='\r')
    print('\n\0338',end='')
    _=msvcrt.getwch()
```

[image: until max line: printing correctly]
[image: over max line: bug?]

when line is over max cmd size(10), bug(?) occurs.
It seems obviously bug to me, and I wonder this is really a bug or there is other way to fix this

tried `\033[s` and `\033[u` too but same, spent many hours but couldn't gained anything

Answer (score 0):

Save/restore cursor save/restore the row/column on the screen.  Scrolling doesn't affect that (your text moved, but the screen did not).